# I am not getting output of variable in .bat file substring

Tags: batch-file, text, substring

In my .bat file below I am getting the following results.

```
@echo off
set result=""
set filteredResult=""
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (outputText.txt) DO (SET result=%%x & SET  filteredResult=%result:~0,5% & echo !filteredResult!)
pause
```

outputText.txt

```
tables
--------------------------
number one
number two
number three
(3) lines
```

Results

```
""
""
""
""
""
""
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why am I not getting a substring of 5 from result.?

Comment: you have a [delayed expanison issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `%` to `!` `filteredResult=%result:~0,5%` to `filteredResult=!result:~0,5!`

```
@echo off
set result=""
set filteredResult=""
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (outputText.txt) DO (SET result=%%x & SET  filteredResult=!result:~0,5! & echo !filteredResult!)
pause
```